# Getting &lt; and &gt; instead of < > while posting code

Tags: syntax-highlighting

[image]hi everyone I am getting this &lt and &gt instead of < and > while posting my code, I am using enlighter plugin,   I was using syntax highlighter before there also I was facing the same problem, frustated. I am frustrated with this please help.

Comment: How do you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you are using the 'enlighter plugin', the best place to ask that question is in their plugin support area.

Provide as much detail as you can about what you are doing, where you are doing, and expected and actual results.

If you have figured out your issue, post an answer here and mark it as correct. That will help others that might stumble on your question when they have a similar problem.

(Old post that needs an answer, or at least something from the OP with further details or a solution.)